# SQLite Query that parses JSON string in a column

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a SQLite database built with ROOM persistence to store Users data.
One of the fields in the User object is a MAP which is stored in the table as Json String

**column name: "user_status"**

```
{"user1":1, "user2":0, "user3":2, ....}
```

Now I want to query through this JSON string to filter the list of users according to their status

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status.user1 = 1
```

How can I manage that?

Comment: I don't think that Android compiles in [the JSON1 SQLite extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html). If I'm correct, then what you want is not supported by SQLite on Android, let alone Room.

Comment: @CommonsWare... JSON1 would have been great, but unfortunately I couldn't find an Android implementation for it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around by using LIKE and parsing the JSON data as String

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status LIKE '%'||:userId||'\":1%' LIMIT 1
```

I know it might not be the best option, but works for now.